# Improve performance of an XSLT template for checking parent and child nodes

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0

I have implemented an XSLT function that takes as inputs a node and its parent node and “gathers” the values of all those data items in the node and returns “True” if all of them are the same or “False” if they are different. The implementation is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://ecs.dgtaxud.ec">
    <xsl:template name="checkUniqueVales">
        <xsl:param name="nodeParentName" select="()"/>
        <xsl:param name="nodeName" select="()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var1" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[matches(local-name(), $nodeParentName)]//*[matches(local-name(), $nodeName)]">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="xs:string((xs:string(fn:count(fn:distinct-values($var1))))='1')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template checkUniqueValues is being called 4 times. It takes as input two parameters, “nodeParentName” and “nodeName”, which represent the name of the parent node and the name of the target node, respectively. It then stores the values of all the target nodes that match the given “nodeName” and are children of the parent nodes that match the given “nodeParentName”. Let me give you an example of an XML

```
<Group>
    <Item>
      <ref>16</ref>
      <countryOfDis>Italy</countryOfDis>
      <countryOfDes>Spain</countryOfDes>
      <Support>
         <method>Transdoc</method>
      </Support>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ref>16</ref>
      <countryOfDis>Italy</countryOfDis>
      <countryOfDes>Spain</countryOfDes>
      <Support>
         <method>Transdoc</method>
      </Support>
    </Item>
</Group>
```

The output by using this function will be for the above xml example where every one of the data items are the same will be

16
Italy
Spain

Transdoc

If for example some are different:

```
<Group>
        <Item>
          <ref>16</ref>
          <countryOfDis>Moldova</countryOfDis>
          <countryOfDes>Ukraine</countryOfDes>
          <Support>
             <method>Transdoc1</method>
          </Support>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <countryOfDis>Italy</countryOfDis>
          <countryOfDes>Spain</countryOfDes>
          <Support>
             <method>Transdoc2</method>
          </Support>
        </Item>
    </Group>
```

and the output will be

```
<Group>
       <ref>16</ref>
        <Item>
          <countryOfDis>Moldova</countryOfDis>
          <countryOfDes>Ukraine</countryOfDes>
          <Support>
             <method>Transdoc1</method>
          </Support>
        </Item>
         <Item>
          <ref>16</ref>
          <countryOfDis>Italy</countryOfDis>
          <countryOfDes>Spain</countryOfDes>
          <Support>
             <method>Transdoc2</method>
          </Support>
        </Item>
    </Group>
```

Dont mind the mapping. Im using altova mapforce. I just want to make the function more performance fast
This function wants to check if ref, countryOfDis countryOfDes and method under Support have the same values for each Item. It took us to input the Item as nodeParentName and countryofDis or countryOfDes or method under Support as nodeName The for each part when the message is big has a big countdown and this is causing issues. Maybe one idea is to somehow break the for each when we find for example two equals and then break from the for each but I don't think this is feasible in XSLT. Any ideas on how to implement this in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance
This is a follow-up of the question [Improve performance of an XSLT function in the for-each part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76678479/improve-performance-of-an-xslt-function-in-the-for-each-part)

Comment: You accepted Michael Kay's answer to your previous question so I would expect the code in the new question to incorporate the suggestions made in that answer. As for the new question, how does the complete code look, are you calling that template four times, what is the expected output?

Comment: @MartinHonnen the expected outlook is that if the values of ref for example are the same at all Items then i keep only the one unique value. The same thing is valid for countryOfDis, countryOfDes and method under support. If the values for these items are the same in every Item then each of these 4 data items will be mapped only once to the output xml..i will update my answer to give you an output xml for each case